# совместимость ASIO BOOST 1.69 и 1.70 - get_io_service().stopped()

Tags: c++, boost, asio

в коде программы используется **boost::asio**, в версии 1.69 все работало,
но при переходе вк версии 1.70 и выше этот код не компилируется

```
ip::tcp::acceptor acc_;
if(acc_.get_io_service().stopped())
```

...

Данный код работает с **boost 1.69**
Как можно изменить данный код, что бы он работал с **boost 1.70+**?
Кусок кода выглядит так

```
        #if BOOST_VERSION != 107000
         if(acc_.is_open() && !acc_.get_io_service().stopped())
        #else
         if(acc_.is_open() && !acc_.get_executor().context().stopped())
        #endif
```

...

Проблема в том что непонятно чем заменить stopped() в данном случае.

Comment: Ну например читать документацию по новой версии, и переписывать код под нее?

Comment: Переведите вопрос полностью на русский язык. Отформатируйте код. Желательно привести [mre]

Comment: [The previously deprecated get_io_context and get_io_service member functions have now been removed](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html)